# Oracle select statement with a function call return value. But when doing insert to a table with same query, function column shows null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

(The query might not make any sense as I have simplified it and changed all column/table names)

```
SELECT some_id,
  (SELECT another_id
  FROM another_id_table
  WHERE some_filter2    = pkg_another.get_another_id(some_id,'X')
  ) AS another_id
FROM some_id_table;
```

The query above return values for another_id column.

If I try below insert statement with the same above query the another_id becomes null in the id_table.

```
INSERT INTO id_table
SELECT some_id,
  (SELECT another_id
  FROM another_id_table
  WHERE some_filter2    = pkg_another.get_another_id(some_id,'X')
  ) AS another_id
FROM some_id_table;
```

Some notes:

I always truncate the id_table before starting the insert statement.
The id_table has the same data types as in the select statement
I have tried to move the another_id query to a view, no difference.

Anybody know why I'm able to query the result but not able to insert the result for another_id column?

Comment: what is the data type of another_id ???

Comment: This is really strange ... Did you manage to reduce your issue to a small but reproducible example? Maybe on http://sqlfiddle.com ? Without more informations, all our answers would be very speculative to say the least...

Comment: The data type is NUMBER (4,0)

Answer (score 0):

That is strange.

Sometimes Oracle gets confused when columns exist in more than one table and you use them without qualifier. (Rather then reporting ambiguity Oracle uses one of the columns then sometimes.)

So maybe it helps to add qualifiers; especially for some_id in `get_another_id(some_id,'X')`. That would be `get_another_id(some_id_table.some_id,'X')`, if some_id belongs to some_id_table, as I suppose.

Comment: If Oracle ever gets "confused", raise an SR - that'd be a bug.